# Angular projects with multiple libs in docker-compose

Tags: angular, npm, docker-compose

I have two Angular projects, each with its own repository, and two libraries in a repository published on the GitLab registry.

Recently, I set up a docker-compose.yml for developers starting the full-stack project.

However, there is a problem:

When a developer wants to test an update on a library within a project, they have to publish a new version of the library. Before using Docker, they could simply use npm link for the library.

I've heard about Nx as a potential solution for better structuring multiple Angular projects, but I'm hesitant to consolidate all projects into a single repository due to concerns about rights management.

The first approach I considered is to mount the library folder inside my Angular project container for linking the library. Are there better way to achieve this?

Thank you.